# Visual Studio 2013 can't find version of Typescript for angular 2 project

Tags: javascript, angularjs, visual-studio

I need to set up a working environment for angular 2 SPA development using VS 2013 (company issues require me to use 2013, I can't use 2015 even though it would make things easier).

I've installed typescript through npm and through the installer Microsoft as available and I'm up to the latest version (1.7.5 as of the moment I'm writing).

I created a Typescript application and I get the following errors on build (without having added any code).

```
Error   1   Your project file uses a different version of the TypeScript compiler and tools than is currently installed on this machine.  No compiler was found at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.7\1.7\tsc.exe.  You may be able to fix this problem by changing the <TypeScriptToolsVersion> element in your project file.
```

The TypeScriptToolsVersion in csproj is at 1.7 which seems fine to me.

```
Error   2   The specified task executable location "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.7\1.7\tsc.exe" is invalid.
```

I'm not sure what this means... do I have to add typescript as a PATH variable? How do I do that?

I was initially developing using WebStorm, which was far more confortable to develop. I just clicked on "gulp" and it would listen for .ts files and .scss and compile them on save. Then clicking npm start would boot up an auto-refreshing client... I wouldn't need to do anything else...

Is it possible to reproduce this working environment in VS somehow? How can I get VS to run my angular 2 app normally?

Answer (score 0):

go to 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.7
copy all file , make new folder rename that to 1.7
and paste all in that

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.7\1.7
!!!
this work for now!

Comment: Yes it did! Amazing! Problem is now I've completely screwed up the csproj file and have no idea how to restore that... Thank you anyways